# What is Bake.columnData in twig template files

Tags: cakephp, twig, cakephp-3.0

In the following statement, what is `Bake.columnData`? This was part of the bake template `form.twig`.

Where can I find more information of what attributes and methods are available? I'm essentially trying to see what `fieldData` contains.

```
{%- set fieldData = Bake.columnData(field, schema) %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bake` is a twig style reference to `$this->Bake`, which is a helper, `\Bake\View\Helper\BakeHelper`, so `Bake.columnData()` is basically [**`$this->Bake->columnData()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.12.0/src/View/Helper/BakeHelper.php#L288).

There's no docs about that specifically, the plugin's **[Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/development.html)** only describes Twig usage in general, so you'll have to dig through [**the source code**](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/1.12.0/src/View/Helper/BakeHelper.php) I'm afraid.

It should be noted that Bake uses **[`wyrihaximus/twig-view`](https://github.com/WyriHaximus/TwigView)**, you can find more information there about its CakePHP specific features. For debugging purposes there's for example the `debug` filter (which maps to CakePHP's `debug()` function), which you could use like this this in your twig template:

```
{% do Bake.columnData(field, schema)|debug %}
```

This will dump the debug output in the generated template file, and will look something like:

```
\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php(418) : eval()'d code (line 103)
########## DEBUG ##########
[
    'type' => 'string',
    'length' => (int) 255,
    'null' => false,
    'default' => null,
    'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'comment' => '',
    'precision' => null
]
###########################
```